# Mass action in Sales order grid

Tags: magento-1.9, order-status, order-grid, massaction

[image: Sales order grid]How to add the new mass action in magento sales order grid to update my custom status.

Answer (score 0):

your config.xml for event calling

```
<events>
            <core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
                <observers>
                    <modulename>
                        <class>modulename/observer</class>
                        <method>addActions</method>
                    </modulename>
                </observers>
            </core_block_abstract_prepare_layout_before>
        </events>
```

your observer function

```
class Spacename_Moudlename_Model_Observer
{
    public function addActions($observer)
        {



         $block = $observer->getEvent()->getBlock();
                if(get_class($block) =='Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Massaction'
                    && $block->getRequest()->getControllerName() == 'sales_order')
                {


                    $block->addItem('--Your Label--', array(
                        'label' => '--Your Label--' ,
                        'url' => '',
                        'target'    => '_blank'
                    ));

              }

    }}
```

Comment: In which config.xml and observer function can i add the given code. @Qaisar Satti

Comment: your module config.xml or you want to add directly??

Comment: Where i mention the action?

Comment: if you asking about the massaction url you can add it 'url' => 'your post action url',

Comment: I'm not sure that's the right event to observe

Comment: i tried this event and it's working without any problem

Comment: Can you please send me the sample post action url?

Comment: 'url' =>Mage::helper("adminhtml")->getUrl('adminrouter/contorlller/action'), you can you url like that